# sub report table header is not displayed on the next page

Tags: reporting

i have a subreport that displays values in table format.
when the values are more part of the table content displays in the next page. i want the table header also to be displayed in the next page when ever the table contents go to the next page.

in the main report i am calling the sub report in detail section of the main report and in subreport i have kept the table header in the page header and table content in the detail section.
when i am rendering the sub report it is printing fine but when call it from the main report it is not displaying the table header.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify what you're even asking. A problem with paging? And likely include some code examples to set some context.

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to elixir-lang? http://elixir-lang.org/

Comment: @Ryan : I am referring to elixir only...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the technology your referring to?  The elixir tag on SO refers to elixir the BEAM compatible language.